# Accessing database file in xcode

Tags: iphone, sql, ios, xcode

I have an existing database file. I want to use this db file in a project. I placed this file in my app folder in mac and dragged the same into Xcode. And now I have written the code to check whether the file exists or not. But it is throwing FALSE exception.

```
 bool databaseAlreadyExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"school.db"];
```

Please let me know how to use the existing db files.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the path with

```
NSString *databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"school" ofType:@"db"];
```

For Swift:

```
let dbPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "school", ofType: "db")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using Core Data in your project, aren't you?
If so take a look at the [iPhone Core Data Recipes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project by Apple!
In the Classes/​RecipesAppDelegate.m you'll find sample code for accomplishing what you need!

There's a good tutorial about pre-loading over at [Ray Wenderlich's site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data).
Shipping a pre-loaded database in the way the Core Data Recipes example showcases is not the most desireable way by Apple. So please take a look at the provided tutorial for a more sophisticated approach!

Comment: Pretty sure he isn't using Core Data if it is an existing DB.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what type of DB it is (MySQL, SQLITE, etc.) the best I can tell you is to find an iOS appropriate library/wrapper to access the database. As an example. [FMBD](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) if very good for SQLITE.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not you need the database to be writable.

You can get access to the database just by doing this:

```
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydb.sqlite"];
```

but if you've copied it to another directory so you can write to it (e.g. the Documents directory), you'd need to do something like this to get the path:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydb.sqlite"];
```